# Using Futures in flutter old versions

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

Android studio is giving me this error

```
info: The class 'Future' wasn't exported from 'dart:core' until version 2.1, but this code is required to be able to run on earlier versions.
```

If I put this

```
import 'dart:async';
```

the problem seems to go away. Could someone explain why this is happening and if this is the correct way to fix this.

Thanks a lot.

---- edit

Can I update dart core to something > 2.1
I am guess it is this line in my pubspec yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"
```

Is there any downsides to doing thins i.e. running on older android/ios versions.

Comment: The error is given when you try to use a `Future` without importing `dart:async` in any version before 2.1. After 2.1 the Future class was exported by dart core so you don't need to import async anymore. Imo you are just better to use the latest dart version and update your dart constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the terminal and execute the following:

```
flutter upgrade
```

This will upgrade both flutter and dart